# Implementing a dropdown on magento navigation

Tags: magento-1.7, php, module, navigation, dropdown-attribute

I'm trying to figure out how I can implement my magento navigation so that certain links when hovered over create a dropdown with more links in.

At the moment to add a new link I create it in the local.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <!-- Add  link  -->
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>ABOUT ProGARM®</label>
                <url>about-progarm</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>ABOUT ProGARM®</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>1</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-about-us"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
             <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>PRODUCTION</label>
                <url>progarm-in-production</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>PRODUCTION</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>1</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-production"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>CE CERTIFICATION</label>
                <url>ce-certification</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>CE CERTIFICATION</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>20</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-cert"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
              <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>QUALITY</label>
                <url>quality</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>QUALITY</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>21</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-quality"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
              <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>PRODUCTS</label>
                <url>products</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>PRODUCTS</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>22</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-quality"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
               <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>VXS+</label>
                <url>the-new-vxs-fabric</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>VXS+</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>23</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-quality"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>

               <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>FABRICS</label>
                <url>fabrics</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>FABRICS</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>25</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-quality"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
              <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>EN-NORMS</label>
                <url>en-norms</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>EN-NORMS</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>26</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-videos"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>VIDEOS</label>
                <url>videogallery</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>VIDEOS</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>26</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-videos"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>CONTACT US</label>
                <url>contacts</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                <title>CONTACT US</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
                <position>27</position>
                <liParams/>
                <aParams>class="top-link-contact"</aParams>
                <beforeText></beforeText>
                <afterText></afterText>
            </action>
```

There is also a file called top.links.phtml which looks like this

```
<?php if ($toplinks && is_array($toplinks)): ?>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
            <?php foreach ($toplinks as $_toplink): ?>
                <li<?php if ($_toplink['first'] || $_toplink['last']): ?> class="<?php if ($_toplink['first']): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if ($_toplink['last']): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_toplink['liParams'] ?>><?php echo $_toplink['beforeText'] ?><a <?php echo $_toplink['aParams'] ?>><?php echo $_toplink['innerText'] ?></a><?php echo $_toplink['afterText'] ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm not sure what steps I need to be taking to accomplish these changes, I can create the drop-down menu in css but not sure how to implement this within magento.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The core implementation of Magento only does a single-level of navigation (that is either a horizontal or vertical bar, no sub-menus).  To change this you need to override the Link block to allow addition of sublinks referencing a parent and then also adjust the template to create the drop-down markup for the links defined in the XML.

The Enterprise Edition, and I believe Professional Edition, have a tool called the CMS Page Hierarchy which allows you to create a real tree of pages which you can read to generate your navigation.